# overflow: hidden breaks border-radius

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble with a container div, border-radius, and overflow.

(For anyone on hubspot, the following question is how to move the footer content outside of the container div)

NOTE: I am stuck inside a CMS template and cannot change the format or content of the HTML. It must rely solely on CSS

The following is the general layout of the website

```
    <div id="container">
       <div id="header">...</div>
       <div id="content">...</div>
       <div id="footer">...</div>
    </div>
```

the css that is applied is the following:

```
#container{
   -moz-border-radius: 15px !important;
   -webkit-border-radius: 15px !important;
   -khtml-border-radius: 15px !important;
   border-radius: 15px !important;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

if I change the overflow:hidden to overflow:visible the border disappears (at least on Chrome). Does anyone know why this happens and whether there is a way around it?

Comment: I know why this happens. A solution without `overflow:hidden` eludes me though

Answer (score 1):

If your asking for why this happens the answer is simple.

Borders in most browsers work in such a manner. Discover a bounding rectangle. Draw the required radius around the bounding rectangle.

The problem is the browsers draw the border on the edge of the bounding rectangle .

So theoretically elements can break through the bounds of the rectangle when they are rounded.

This is the overflow. So if `overflow:visible` the edges might not be clean.

**Why does `overflow:hidden` fix this**

Well its simple overflow:hidden just hides anything outside the bounds of a bounding rectangle. Hence and therefore this would clean up your border

Answer (score 0):

i have been using radius on buttons, and sometimes the `!important;` crashes the ruleset when used on border radius, then removing `!important` causes the ruleset to work again...

(found out while tweaking css of some websites)

Comment: He never said his ruleset was crashed? The border works but it just has an overflow problem